# Find recursively a directory and remove it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory db-cache-db and there are a bunch of them under /home/{USER}/public_html. I know there is a way to write a script to that but I am not sure where or how to start.

I tried the following but no luck

```
find /home -wholename 'db-cache-db' -exec echo "rm -rf" {} ';'
```

Do I need to use -type and -name?

Comment: So what did it do? Did it echo what you asked it to?

Comment: Be careful people executing this command, it can be dangerous if not properly deployed!

Comment: It didn;t find the direcotires to remove them

Comment: `find -delete` should work.

Answer (score 3):

`-wholename` is the same as `-path`, and matches the *full path* of the directory, e.g. `/home/{USER}/public_html/db-cache-db`, not just the name, e.g. `db-cache-db`. Since you don't use a wildcard argument (e.g. `*/db-cache-db`), you'll never find anything.

Try the following first, to make sure you'll not accidentally delete more than you intended:

```
find /home -name 'db-cache-db' -type d
```

If this results in the directories you want to delete, add the last argument that actually deleted:

```
find /home -name 'db-cache-db' -type d -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a safe thing to do:

```
find /home -name 'db-cache-db' -type d -exec echo rm -rf {} ';'
```

You could lose lots of directories you want to keep.

```
find /home -name 'db-cache-db' -exec echo "rm -rf" {} ';' > /home/tmp.shl
```

Next read what is in `tmp.shl,` be sure everything is safe.
Execute the script you "wrote" with find.

```
chmod +x /home/tmp.shl 
/home/tmp.shl
```

Comment: `-exec echo` is *very* safe, it just prints.

Comment: The original did not have echo.  FWIW.

Comment: Rather than use `-exec echo rm ...` where you could accidently forget to type `echo`, isn't it the same effect to test using `-print`.

Comment: @KevinFegan I've used `echo rm` or similar before, to *show me the commands* that will get executed. If I only wanted the file names though, `-print` would be sufficient.